# Crossfading with multiple images CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, banner

I am trying to make a banner which looks like this : https://youtu.be/yQbtmsB9dB0

But the pictures which are radius bordered are not appearing on the screen by order and transition. I had to make a crossfading transition but I am stuck for hours. Here is my HTML & Javascript & CSS codes.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="3.css">


<div id="banner"></div>
<div id="circle"></div>
<span id="popkupon"> POPÜLER KUPONLAR </span>
<div class="profil1" div> 
    <img id="i1" img class="img-circle" img src="dosyalar/1.jpg" Width="58" height="58">
    <img id="i2" img class="img-circle" img src="dosyalar/2.jpg" Width="58" height="58">
    <img id="i3" img class="img-circle" img src="dosyalar/3.jpg" Width="58" height="58">
    <img id="i4" img class="img-circle" img src="dosyalar/4.jpg" Width="58" height="58">
    <img id="i5" img class="img-circle" img src="dosyalar/5.jpg" Width="58" height="58">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

See at: https://jsfiddle.net/kasqwdbc/

I am open for any kind of suggestion I would be really appreciated for your help.

Comment: banner link is blank

Comment: The link to the banner doesn't work for me

Comment: https://youtu.be/yQbtmsB9dB0 here is the video link of banner

Comment: @Gerard i put the youtube video link can you check it please?